# what should http should be returned to the client when asking to update a record that either was not found or was not updated?

Tags: rest, http

Im using a mysql library that when I perform an update to the database if get a number back `1/0` that represent:

```
if record was not found 0 returned

if record found and something was changed 1 returned

if record found and nothing was not changed 0 returned
```

So I want to return the use 200 when record found and something was changed, and im trying to think what should I return the user if result is 0? should it also be 200? maybe the user should know that a record was not found...

the thing is i dont want to make more calls to see if there is a record and then perform the update, i want to keep it with as less calls possible...

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ideal case should be:

- use `200 OK / 204 No Content` if a record successfully updated
- `404 Not Found` if a record not found
- `409 Conflict` if a record is not updated

Right now your main problem sounds like "server cannot determine the real reason for failed update". Cause server cannot do this, it cannot decide whether send 404 or 409 status.

With all this, you are in a situation that now it is the Client who doesn't know what is failed during update if the server returns any status rather than OK (200/204). And this force Client anyway does additional requests to determine the real reason.

---

What you can do to avoid an additional check on the server for each request, is to do verify whether a resource exists or not only for failed cases. In other words

- do update query -> if the query returns 0  do another select query to check resource existing

Comment: i know, thats the ideal situation, but the only indication that i have is 1 and 0, and 0 representing both case, record not found and record is not updated....so is there a result that can work for both? maybe 409?

Comment: or i can make more db calls to verify which is which but that is a bummer cause i dont want to make calls for things like this

Comment: @MNY what about doing additional call on server, if update returns 0, to check the real reason? See otherwise you anyway force client to double check the real status of things, as any status from the server (rather then 200/204) will not explain to him whether resource not exists or update failed (as the server also don't know this).

Comment: that is a good suggestion. thanks i will do that. then i minimise the additional calls and make them only when its 0.

Comment: @MNY have updated answer accordingly, would you accept?)